# How to beta test app across Android and iOS with in app purchases?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, beta

I've got an app that is almost ready for a closed beta test. This is the first app I've attempted to publish. For the app to demonstrate all its features some of the testers will need to subscribe to a feature locked behind an in app purchase. This will write a value to my database acknowledging that the feature has been bought, but also creates a couple of problems. The user purchases time during which the feature is unlocked, they can always purchase more.

On iOS any purchases that are made while part of a beta test are free. This means that a tester will be able to purchase as much time as they want, really loading up. When the test ends the purchases are supposed to be inaccessible because an app in TestFlight is treated as a different app to the same app released. However, both apps will look for the value in the same place in my database, meaning they will keep all purchases.

On Android any purchases, including the app itself, are made with the testers own money. However, I can offer promotional codes to gift them the app or in app purchases for free.

The problem is that to prevent iOS users from keeping all purchases I'll have to wipe the iap values from my database. I cannot distinguish between an iOS purchase and an Android purchase, so the Android purchases would be removed too. I would have to come up with some way to make sure Android testers do no purchase in app purchases with real money during the test, because that money would be lost to them. I would also have to manage some method for Android testers to receive the app and iap promo codes.

Is there any straightforward way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why not price the IAP at 0 during the testing process and then raise the price before release?

Comment: @Paulw11, it seems the Google Play store requires that all IAPs be at least $1 USD.